# Trying to get subdomains working locally with codeigniter and mamp

Tags: apache, codeigniter, subdomain, mamp

I'm trying to follow this tut http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/ to get subdomains working locally.

I've added this to the /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       snapgiftapp.com
127.0.0.1       test1.snapgiftapp.com
127.0.0.1       test2.snapgiftapp.com
```

and i've added this to the end of the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/snapGiftAppFront"  
    ServerName snapgiftapp.com  
    ServerAlias snapgiftapp.com  

    <Directory "/Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/snapGiftAppFront">  
        Options -Indexes  
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/snapGiftApp"  
    ServerName snapgiftapp.com  
    ServerAlias *.snapgiftapp.com  

    <Directory "/Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/snapGiftApp">  
        Options -Indexes  
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

When I point my browser to snapgiftapp.com or test1.snapgiftapp.com, I get the same site located in the snapGiftAppFront folder

Comment: When you ping snapgiftapp.com does it reply from 127.0.0.1? What happens if you open http://snapgiftapp.com:8888/ in browser?

Comment: Ok i've changed my mamp port to 80 instead of 8888 and now when I point my browser to snapgiftapp.com or test1.snapgiftapp.com, it's pulling up the same site (the snapGiftAppFront site).

Comment: @MilanBabuškov now that i've changed my mamp port to 80, if I go to snapgiftapp.com:80, it shows the same page as it does if I go to snapgiftapp.com and it actually removes the :80 from the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into the mamp configurations and change the port to 80 instead of 8888.